# how to inject an instance of configuration when creating instance of the injected class?

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, guice

I have a simple situation:

```
class MyClass @Inject() (configuration: Configuration) {

    val port = configuration.get[String]("port")

    ...

}
```

and now I want to use MyClass in some other object:

```
object Toyota extends Car {

  val myClass = new MyClass(???)

  ...

}
```

but I dont know how when I use MyClass i give it the configuration instance i annotated that will be injected when MyClass is going to be instantiated..

im using play2.6/juice/scala

thanks!

Comment: you can't. (Well, you could, if you knew the specifics of the library you were using, but that would just completely defeat the purpose, wouldn't it?). That's not how you are you supposed to use dependency injection. But, before you ask me how you are supposed to use it, let me tell you this: don't use dependency injection. Really. There is a whole new class of problems you would avoid by simply good-old passing your dependencies around as parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should decide if dependency injection is really what you need. Basic idea of DI: instead of factories or objects themselves creating new objects, you externally pass the dependencies, and pass the instantiation problem to someone else.

You suppose to go all in with it if you rely on framework, that is why no way of using **`new`** along with DI. You cannot pass/inject a class into the scala object, here is a draft of what you can do:

Play/guice require some preparation.

Injection Module to tell guice how to create objects (if you cannot do this if annotations, or want to do it in one place).

```
class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    // ...
    bind(classOf[MyClass])
    bind(classOf[GlobalContext]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Inject the injector to be able to access it.

```
class GlobalContext @Inject()(playInjector: Injector) {
  GlobalContext.injectorRef = playInjector
}

object GlobalContext {
  private var injectorRef: Injector = _

  def injector: Injector = injectorRef
}
```

Specify which modules to enable, because there can be more than one.

```
// application.conf
play.modules.enabled += "modules.InjectionModule"
```

And finally the client code.

```
object Toyota extends Car {

  import GlobalContext.injector

  // at this point Guice figures out how to instantiate MyClass, create and inject all the required dependencies
  val myClass = injector.instanceOf[MyClass]

  ...

}
```

A simple situation expanded with a frameworks help. So, you should really consider other possibilities. Maybe it would be better to pass the configs as an implicit parameter in your case?

For dependency injection with guice take a look at:
[ScalaDependencyInjection with play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) and [Guice wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki)

Comment: if i change `class MyClass (implicit configuration: Configuration) {` doesent it means that `object Toyota extends Car {` needs to have `Configuration` in its scope..? or i can just create `val myClass = new MyClass` like this?

Comment: Yes, you would need an implicit `Configuration` in the scope in order to use it, because it isn't some global information of the application. But then it provides cleaner code for passing around this `Configuration`. [Where do Implicits Come From?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits)